# Does Spring boot Support Fast fail on Liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

From [Spring DB Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) docs, Spring boot DB initialization using Spring JDBC supports
feature Fast fail - that means if there are any issues in DB init script or migration scripts then Spring boot Context initialization failed. as result Spring boot server won't start.

now can we have this functionality when we use Advanced DB Migration tool like liquibase?

Spring Docs Doesn't say anything about this in liquibase section. Does this feature only works in Spring JDBC initialization?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the desired behaviour using 'Preconditions'.
On default, it actually *will* fail fast, but you can overwrite it (example using SQL syntax):

```
-- preconditions onFail:WARN onError:WARN
```

Available parameters:

> HALT: Immediately halt the execution of the entire changelog. [DEFAULT]
>   CONTINUE: Skip over the changeset. Execution of the change set will be
>   attempted again on the next update. Continue with the changelog.
>   MARK_RAN: Skip over the changeset, but mark it as executed. Continue
>   with the changelog.   WARN    Output a warning and continue executing the
>   changeset / changelog as normal.

see https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html

Comment: as you said, I have check liquibase  master.xml there is no explicitly set this precondition and default one should fast fail. But its not happending Any idea why its not happening?

Comment: This property gets set within the ChangeSet, not the master.xml. Have a look at the ChangeSet (probably XML, but might also be YAML, plain SQL or JSON, depending on your setup).

Answer (score -1):

whenever there is an issue in your liquibase script, application won't start because datasource is not properly initialised.

Comment: that's Not ture. project In which I am working will throw Liquibase migration exception on output and and rest spring boot context loading resumes.